# iOS swift while loop freeze my app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app where a user choose his accommodation and pick a time from date picker so the user can know what time the buss will arrive to his accommodation , on the simulator and iPad I'm having the appropriate results however I'm facing this issue on iPhone real device, this is the code :

```
mTimeString = "5:07 AM"
```

it will be searched in the array if not found , minus seconds until it matches results in the array . but while loop is freezing my app , i tried to surround it by :

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT ,0)
dispatch_async(queue){}
```

its not freezing anymore but the I'm not getting the results according to the array

```
if(defaults.stringForKey(accommodationChoiceKey)?.toInt() == 40) {

    var  array = ["12:05 AM","12:25 AM","12:45 AM","1:05 AM","1:25 AM","1:45 AM","2:05 AM","2:25 AM","2:45 AM","3:05 AM","3:25 AM","3:45 AM","4:05 AM","4:25 AM","4:45 AM","5:05 AM","5:25 AM","5:45 AM","6:05 AM","6:25 AM","6:45 AM","7:05 AM","7:25 AM","7:45 AM","8:05 AM","8:25 AM","8:45 AM","9:05 AM","9:25 AM","9:45 AM","10:05 AM","10:25 AM","10:45 AM","11:05 AM","11:25 AM","11:45 AM","12:05 PM","12:25 PM","12:45 PM","1:05 PM","1:25 PM","1:45 PM","2:05 PM","2:25 PM","2:45 PM","3:05 PM","3:25 PM","3:45 PM","4:05 PM","4:25 PM","4:45 PM","5:05 PM","5:25 PM","5:45 PM","6:05 PM","6:25 PM","6:45 PM","7:05 PM","7:25 PM","7:45 PM","8:05 PM","8:25 PM","8:45 PM","9:05 PM","9:25 PM","9:45 PM","10:05 PM","10:25 PM","10:45 PM","11:05 PM","11:25 PM","11:45 PM"]
    while (find(array, mTimeString) == nil) {
        choiceToSeconds--
        var newmTime = x.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(choiceToSeconds))
        var mTimeString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newmTime)
        if (find(array, mTimeString) != nil) {
            transportationLabel.text = mTimeString
            break
        }
        getReady(newmTime)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not familliar with swift but wouldnt it save you 59 iterations per minute off if you use choiceToSeconds * 60 because as far as i know dateByAddingTimeInterval uses seconds

Comment: i tried that  , still freezing @SergeBekenkamp

Comment: Never said it would fix it, i just said you would save 59 iterations for every minute the time is off.

Comment: okay bro, no problem @SergeBekenkamp

Comment: What is x? And how is the dateFormatter defined? Adding print to values within the while loop should show you what's going on.

Comment: Add `println(mTimeString)` after you set it in the loop. (And by the way, change it to be a let instead of a var.)

Comment: **var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle**

,x is the time from the date picker which is passed to this function, choiceToSeconds is deducted from this Time and then compared to the values in the array , if found display it , if not minus seconds and compare until found then display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating on Background thread which is okay , but you should NEVER update UI element from background thread ( transportationLabel.text = mTimeString ) , this should be done from main Thread , for example

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

         if(defaults.stringForKey(accommodationChoiceKey)?.toInt() == 40) {

                var  array = ["12:05 AM","12:25 AM","12:45 AM","1:05 AM","1:25 AM","1:45 AM","2:05 AM","2:25 AM","2:45 AM","3:05 AM","3:25 AM","3:45 AM","4:05 AM","4:25 AM","4:45 AM","5:05 AM","5:25 AM","5:45 AM","6:05 AM","6:25 AM","6:45 AM","7:05 AM","7:25 AM","7:45 AM","8:05 AM","8:25 AM","8:45 AM","9:05 AM","9:25 AM","9:45 AM","10:05 AM","10:25 AM","10:45 AM","11:05 AM","11:25 AM","11:45 AM","12:05 PM","12:25 PM","12:45 PM","1:05 PM","1:25 PM","1:45 PM","2:05 PM","2:25 PM","2:45 PM","3:05 PM","3:25 PM","3:45 PM","4:05 PM","4:25 PM","4:45 PM","5:05 PM","5:25 PM","5:45 PM","6:05 PM","6:25 PM","6:45 PM","7:05 PM","7:25 PM","7:45 PM","8:05 PM","8:25 PM","8:45 PM","9:05 PM","9:25 PM","9:45 PM","10:05 PM","10:25 PM","10:45 PM","11:05 PM","11:25 PM","11:45 PM"]
                while (find(array, mTimeString) == nil) {
                    choiceToSeconds--
                    var newmTime = x.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(choiceToSeconds))
                    var mTimeString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newmTime)
                    if (find(array, mTimeString) != nil) {

                        //  This should be done on Main Thread
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            transportationLabel.text = mTimeString
                        }      


                        break
                    }
                    getReady(newmTime)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: got error on ^ ... ^ is not a prefix unary operator

Comment: yeah , looks like you missed ^ before opening the block for dispatch_queue and I just copied it , now I have replaced it , but the main part is label accessing

Comment: still the same i guess the problem is with matching the results with the array elements , because i think the results are not AM or PM thats why it doesn't find them in the array , i have to find a way for the result to be in AM or PM so it search for it in the array, on the simulator it gives correct results on the iPhone it doesn't

Comment: i found the solution after more than 9 hours working .. i had to put region format to united states

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
transportationLabel.text = mTimeString
```

by

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
     transportationLabel.text = mTimeString
}];
```

UI operations must be executed from main thread

EDIT:

In Swift:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
    transportationLabel.text = mTimeString
})
```

Comment: is this swift?       @THIBAUD

Comment: thanks for swift version , but still the app doesn't freeze but I'm not getting the results according to the array